# how can I get div attribute vlaue in bs4?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Currently I have access to the links in the div element but these links are not complete

this is my url :

```
https://digimovie.sbs/maigret-night-at-the-crossroads/
```

this is part of my node:

```
<div class="on_trailer_bottom" data-trailerlink="https://dl3.freeserver.top/st01/film/Trailer/Maigrets.Night.at.the.Crossroads.2017.Trailer.mp4">
```

and here is my code

```
url = 'https://digimovie.sbs/maigret-night-at-the-crossroads/'

site = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
                    site.encoding = site.apparent_encoding
soup = BeautifulSoup(site.content, 'lxml')
trailer_link = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'on_trailer_bottom'})

print(trailer_link['data-trailerlink'])
```

and it's result  :

`https://.freeserver.top`

While it should be like this :

```
https://dl3.freeserver.top/st01/film/Trailer/Maigrets.Night.at.the.Crossroads.2017.Trailer.mp4
```

is problem is in my code or is the site restricted?

Comment: you may have the most common problem: page may use `JavaScript` to add/update elements but `BeautifulSoup`/`lxml`, `requests`/`urllib` can't run `JS`. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  to control real web browser which can run `JS`. OR use (manually) `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab `Network`) to see if `JavaScript` reads data from some URL. And try to  use this URL with `requests`. `JS` usually gets `JSON` which can be easy converted to Python dictionary (without `BS`). You can also check if page has (free) `API` for programmers.

Comment: better show url for this page so we could see real page in browser and check if it use JavaScript to add value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply
Unfortunately, this site does not have an api and my only problem was accessing this link
Using selenium takes a long time
So I think it's better to ignore this part

Comment: @furas this is my url if you can check it I will be grateful ` https://digimovie.sbs/maigret-night-at-the-crossroads/`

Comment: you should add this url in question (when you was writing question) so more people could see it and more people could help you.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem - I get full url using your `soup.find()`. Better show minimal working code which we could copy and test. You could also test what you get in HTML from server. Maybe it was temporary mistake on page. OR maybe it send some useful information in HTML - like message for bots/script or Captcha.

Comment: weird, your code gives me the exact result you expect.

Comment: @SergeyK i have no idea whats going on

Comment: @Mohammad try `trailer_link = soup.find('div', class_='on_trailer_bottom').get('data-trailerlink')` but I have no idea why. the site does not use ajax or javascript

Comment: @SergeyK still same result  `https://.freeserver.top`

Comment: I would repeat: (1) create minimal working code (with all elements, even with `imports`) so we could simply copy and test it on our computers. (2) Check what you get in  `site.content` - maybe server send different content to different users, or to different devices - and maybe it will need to add other elements - like header `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0`

Comment: you could also check if you run correct code - maybe you make modification on one script but you run different script which gets something different. You could add some `print()` to check if you can see it when you run script.

Comment: @furas that was true modification was issue thanks for help my friend